# Updating state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Below is my state object

```
const state = {
  campaign: [{
    id: 1,
    products: [{
        id: 11,
        isWishlist: true
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        isWishlist: true
      },
    ]
  },
            {
    id: 2,
    products: [{
        id: 13,
        isWishlist: true
      },
      {
        id: 14,
        isWishlist: true
      },
    ]
  }]
}
```

Now in UI, there is an action which makes `isWishlist` property to get changed. In order for the app to re-render, how should I update the state, i.e.

```
  updateCampaignProdList = (payload) => {
    const filteredProdColl = []
    this.state.campaignList.map(campaign => {
      filteredProdColl.push(campaign.products.filter(product => product.id === payload.id))
    })
    const prodClicked = filteredProdColl[0][0]
    this.setState({
      campaignList: this.state.campaignList.map(campaign => {
        campaign.products.map(product => {
          if (product.id !== prodClicked.id) {
            return product
          } else {
            return Object.assign({}, product, {
              isWishlist: !(product.isWishlist)
            })
          }
        })
        return Object.assign({}, campaign, {
          products: campaign.products
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

Is this how the state should be updated, also I am getting `flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key,` warning.

`payload` above is the response from the api, that has id of the product changed,

---

### Update

Thanks @Panther for guiding it, below is my complete code

```
updateCampaignProdList = (payload) => {
    const filteredProdColl = []

    this.state.campaignList.map(campaign => {
      const prodArr = campaign.products.filter(product => product.id === payload.id)
      if (prodArr.length !== 0) {
        filteredProdColl.push(prodArr)
      }
    })

    const prodClicked = filteredProdColl[0][0]

    let newCampaignList = [].concat(this.state.campaignList.map(campaign => {
      let newCampaign = {
        ...campaign,
        products: campaign.products.map(product => {
          if (product.id === prodClicked.id) {
            let newProduct = {
              ...product,
              is_wishlist: !product.is_wishlist
            }
            return newProduct
          }
          return product
        })
  }
  return newCampaign
}))

this.setState({
  campaignList: newCampaignList
})
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The way you are updating is ok, but includes too much complexity. Simplify it like below

```
updateCampaignProdList = (payload) => {
 const filteredProdColl = this.state.campaignList.map(campaign => {
   return campaign.products.filter(product => product.id === payload.id)
 })
 const prodClicked = filteredProdColl[0][0]
 let newCampaignList = [].concat(this.state.campaignList.map(campaign => {
    return campaign.products.map(product => {
      if (product.id === prodClicked.id) {
        let newProduct = {
           ...product,
           isWishlist: !product.isWishlist
        }
        return newProduct;
      }
      return product
    })
  })

 this.setState({
  campaignList: newCampaignList
 })
}
```

The reason for `Encountered two children with the same key` is that when you are making a loop(probably a map of products) inside your render, you should assign `key` attribute to the root of the returned JSX. More can be read from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Few issues I got with above, i.e. `map is not a function`, and when I fixed that I got `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'isWishlist' of object`

Comment: i have updated the answer for `map is not a function`, but however i dont see how the product is readonly. give this a try.

Comment: I tried this on my product `Object.isFrozen(product)`, it's returning true, I am using apollo client, maybe that is causing the issue.

Comment: Could be. The object could have been created as `non Extensible`. You can create a new product and return it as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: This worked ! Thanks @Panther, just edit it with triple dots of spread operator instead of four :)

Comment: `[].concat(this.state.campaignList)` is terrible, why not simply call `slice()` You don't even need to call it because `map` is returning a new array anyway?, Also, your first `map` should return the `filteredProdColl` instead of pushing manually in every iteration.

Comment: Actually `concat` is faster in most browser implementations than `slice`. Some past discussion over it is here https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/243.  And yes returning filteredProdColl would be better than pushing since its a map. Did not give it a deep thought

Comment: @Panther Over-optimization < clear code. Note that it's not even needed, `map` already returns a new array.